# How to automate visiting links then submitting a form?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm developing an extension that if opened in a specific page it will collect all forms links in that page, then it should visit each link and  fill the form and submit it. i don't mind if it is visible or in the background.

I know how to do these separately:

- collect the links
- open a link
- fill and send a form

but i need help on how can i combine those at once, visit all the links and fill/submit each one. any hint?

I'm looking to do something similar to what i can do with Selenium. but in chrome extension.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

1: inject the content script to the target page.
The script collect the links, and send the link addresses to background script (service worker) background.js by `chrome.runtime.sendMessage().`

2: Background script add listener for the message by `chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener()`,
and the listener do the following for each link.

```
const tab = await chrome.tabs.create({url: <url_of_the_ilnk>})
chrome.scripting.executeScript({
    target: {tabId: tab.id}, function:yourFunction
});
```

where, `yourFunction()` do fill and send form.